# Видимость ip-шников с двух сетевых карт в подсеть

Tags: linux, ip, iptables, ping, arp

Есть сервер:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0

eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000 link/ether 00:1e:67:c5:ed:69 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff inet 172.16.4.19/24 scope global eth0
int2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000 link/ether 00:e0:ed:34:3f:ab brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff inet 172.16.4.23/24 scope global int2
```

`$ ip r`

```
default via 172.16.4.1 dev eth0 
172.16.4.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.4.19 
172.16.4.0/24 dev int2  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.4.23
```

`int2` не подключен к локальной сети, но почему-то `ping 172.16.4.23` есть и `$ ip neigh show`

```
 172.16.4.19 dev eth0 lladdr 00:1e:67:c5:ed:69 STALE
 172.16.4.23 dev eth0 lladdr 00:1e:67:c5:ed:69 REACHABLE
```

или `$ arp -a`

```
 ? (172.16.4.19) at 00:1e:67:c5:ed:69 [ether] on eth0
 ? (172.16.4.23) at 00:1e:67:c5:ed:69 [ether] on eth0
```

в системе нет никаких правил обработки пакетов, все по дефолту. Есть догадки почему так... но все же хотелось бы явно узнать об этом, если есть инфа киньте ссылки пожалуйста или напишите доходчиво тут. Вопрос: какие есть способы избежать этой особенности? Спасибо.

думал что такое поведение, которое я получил будет только при `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`, но к моему удивлению оказывается интерфейсы в системе неизолированы - сетевой стек в linux реализован так, но вот как его заставить работать изолировано по каждому интерфейсу, причем в дефолтном netns (если это возможно)- вот в раскрытом виде мой вопрос.

Предложенный ответ с изменениме обработки arp запросов для меня подходит

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore=1
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_announce=2
```

Но возможно есть другие вариаты... ?

Comment: А результаты ping и arp даны с какой машины ? Если с той же - то очень странно, машина сама себя по arp видеть не может. Если же это с другой машины в сети - то все ок. у вас там подсеть /24 значит на 23 адрес шлется arp запрос, а linux отвечает на arp (и на другие пакеты) с любого своего интерфейса на любой ip поднятый как локальный

Comment: да с другой машины в сети...
почему так (нет "изоляции" интерфейсов в системе)?
как "изоляцию" можно сделать?

Comment: `iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -d 172.16.4.23 -j DROP` правда на arp он конечно продолжит отвечать, но это не страшно, а если страшно, то надо будет arptables использовать

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ, но я ищу решение  более обобщенное, прописывать каждый раз новое правило, не подходит...

Comment: Чесно сказать я никогда ранее не назначал ip из одной подсети на разные   интерфейсы и думал что такое поведение, которое я получил будет только при net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1, но  к моему удивлению оказывается интерфейсы в системе неизолированы - сетевой стек в linux реализован так, но вот как его заставить работать изолировано по каждому интерфейсу, причем в дефолтном netns (если это возможно)- вот в раскрытом виде мой вопрос.

Comment: http://blog.cj2s.de/archives/29-Preventing-ARP-flux-on-Linux.html

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно... Если найдутся еще варианты  пишите... Заранее спасибо...